# NodeJS: zlib.gunzip( body ) erroneously returns `undefined`

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, http, gzip

I have a barebones node server that parses XML files (referenced from user-defined URLs) and outputs the manipulated data as a CSV file for download.

I'm trying to implement optional GZIP decompression:

```
function loadURL(req, res) {
    request.get(req.query.url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (req.query.isGzip == 'true') {
            zlib.gunzip(body, function(err, dezipped) {
                var xmlData = dezipped.toString('utf-8');
                parseAndOffload(xmlData, req, res);
            });
        } else {
            parseAndOffload(body, req, res);
        }
    });
}
```

Despite the test URL (http://flowercard.co.uk/google_product_feed.xml.gz) being a genuine GZip file with 500kb of data, passing the GZIP file body to `dezipped.toString('utf-8')` returns `undefined`.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely that `body` is a string, and `zlib.gunzip()` is expecting a stream/buffer.

Try setting `encoding: null` as an option.

> encoding - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If null, the body is returned as a Buffer.

```
request.get(req.query.url, {encoding: null}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (req.query.isGzip == 'true') {
        zlib.gunzip(body, function(err, dezipped) {
            var xmlData = dezipped.toString('utf-8');
            parseAndOffload(xmlData, req, res);
        });
    } else {
        parseAndOffload(body, req, res);
    }
});
```

Comment: The internet genuinely astounds me with it's rapidity. Thanks very much, that's done the job.